# Why do Drupal.behaviours and document.ready behave differently?

Tags: 6, javascript

I have the same piece of jQuery that works differently depending whether it is wrapped in document.ready or Drupal.behaviours. The code is intended to enumerate a list of tabs generated by the vertical tabs module.

Using

```
Drupal.behaviors.myModule = function (context) {  
   $('ul.vertical-tabs-list li').each(function(i){
     console.log(i);
   })
}
```

Logs no output, but the following works as expected.

```
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('ul.vertical-tabs-list li').each(function(k){
      console.log(k);
      })
    }) 
 }
```

Why is there a difference and how can I get the first version to work?

Comment: Did you try something like: $('ul.vertical-tabs-list li', context) [...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal.behaviours are similar to document.ready but Drupal make sures that on every ajax call code written in a Drupal.behaviour is executed again. While code written in document.ready is called once on page load.

Comment: Cool, I get that. But still not sure why the first version produces no output. Does that mean behaviours is _only_ called on an ajax request?